# Fiscal printer FP-80II RT implementation using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, laravel, printers, thermal-printer, pos

I am trying to integrate Fiscal Printer FP-80II RT in my web based application but i am unable to integrate it somehow.

below is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var location_epson_ip = "192.168.1.156";
        var data_to_send_version =  '<printerFiscalReport><displayText operator="1" data="Message on customer display" /><printZReport operator="1" timeout="30" /></printerFiscalReport>';
        var epos_version = new epson.fiscalPrint();
        epos_version.onreceive = function (res, tag_list_names, add_info_version){
         }
        epos_version.send(window.location.protocol + "//" + location_epson_ip + "/cgi-bin/fpmate.cgi", data_to_send_version);
       </script>
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong or how it should be so i can print an invoice.

Comment: There seems to be a demo program source on `Intelligent FP SDK for JavaScript Mar 2018\demoWebApplication\fp_demo_web_2018_03_23_V126`, has it been tried?

Comment: yes i tried it but it has alot of functionalities and i don't know which functionality we have to select.

Comment: i just need to have an example of how we can implement it. the demo examples which they gave us is very confusing for me.

Comment: It seems that the Doc folder of the SDK has a description of the start sequence and printing function. For more information, please contact your printer dealer or EPSON.